# see the full path of a file in another directory in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to display the full path of a file, which is in another directory in linux.

for example i am in /home/user/test, and i want to see from there the path of the file fl1 which is lets say in /home/user/test2/fl1, but actually i don't know where fl1 is, and i want to print its path to the terminal .

Comment: can you detail a bit more on what exactly you are trying to accomplish  ?

Comment: know you, that this file is `../test2/fl1`? or only `fl1`? may be you are looking for `find`?

Comment: i want to print in the terminal the full path of a file or a directory which is in a random directory.

Comment: i know just that the fl1 exists. i don't know where it is

Comment: what if more than one `fl1` exists?

Comment: All is about symlinks guys ;)

Comment: Try `find -name fl1`

Comment: @sputnick, but he does not know `/path/to/file` only filename, he wants `find`, I think

Answer (score 2):

If you know where `fl1` is, you can use **realpath(1)**. 
 
`realpath fl1` will print `/home/user/test2/fl1`.

```
NAME
   realpath - return the canonicalised absolute pathname

SYNOPSIS
   realpath [-s|--strip] [-z|--zero]  filename  ...
   realpath --h|--help
   realpath --v|--version
```

See `man 1 realpath` or http://linux.die.net/man/1/realpath for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing to discover the real path of a *symlink*

```
readlink -f /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find an arbitrary file that you don't know where is, run

```
   find / -name name_of_the_file
```

There could ofcourse be several files with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -a
```

will display the files , directories and those directories files and sub-directories